# Узнать, через сколько часов лето

Tags: javascript, время

Нужно узнать, через сколько часов будет лето + какой первый день недели лета.
Всё на JavaScript.

Comment: Очень интересно. А в чём состоит ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В JavaScript есть функция    `Date()` используйте ее для получения и указания времени. 
 
Всю полезную информацию можете получить тут: [Работа с датой и временем в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime)

Для получения разницы мы сначала получим текущее время в числовом виде:

```
var millseconds = +new Date;
```

Далее переводим миллисекунды в часы:

```
var hours= millseconds/(3600 * 100);
```

Следующее лето в методе Date:

```
var millseconds_next = +new Date(2017,5,1);
```

Так же переводим миллисекунды в часы:

```
var hours_next = millseconds_next/(3600 * 100);
```

Наша разница в часах и есть то время:

```
var next = hours_next - hours;
```

Comment: Я знаю, но не знаю, как реализовать.

Comment: Обратите внимание, месяцы в JavaScript указываются от 0 до 11!